# Setting the style.maxWidth from a variable

Tags: javascript, css, variables

My cod is this:

```
<img src="img.png">

<dd id="123">COMMENT</dd>

<script>
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
alert(this.width);
}
img.src = 'img.png';
</script>
```

This alerts a window with width of an img.png. The question is: how to set this width value for an element I need.

Something like:

```
document.getElementById('123').style.maxWidth = this.width;
```

Instead of:

```
alert(this.width);
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('123').style.maxWidth = this.width;` So what happened when you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `width` DOM property of an image is going to be a number.

The CSS `max-width` property only accepts a **length** as its value.

You need to add units to your number.

```
= this.width + "px";
```

Comment: Thank you! You made my day.